# Error:Execution failed for task 'android:mergeReleaseResources'. > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Tags: android, android-build

How can I find the exact png file which is wrong?. Android build tool is displaying the error as "Some file crunching failed"

Comment: Are you not getting the file name which is causing this? Android studio does show the file name.

Comment: I am not getting the file name it just says "Some file crunching failed". I see it displays the file name on some others system

Comment: Sometimes the crunching failure comes in 9-patch image. Do you have any 9-patch images in your project? If yes, delete them and add them again. It works sometimes.

Comment: I know the file which  Cruncher is unable to do the task and it is not 9-patch. But my concern is build tool says some file crunching failed in my system and it shows the exact file name in other system